# Filter a XML file based on another XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML file:

```xml
    <isis xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-clns-isis-cfg">
        <instances>
            <instance>
                <instance-name>ISIS-TEST</instance-name>
                <running></running>
                <overload-bits>
                    <overload-bit>
                        <level>level2</level>
                        <overload-bit-mode>startup-period</overload-bit-mode>
                        <hippity-period>360</hippity-period>
                    </overload-bit>
                </overload-bits>
                <is-type>level2</is-type>
                <nets>
                    <net>
                        <net-name>49.0088.0088.2000.0088.00</net-name>
                    </net>
                </nets>
                <afs>
                    <af>
                        <af-name>ipv4</af-name>
                        <saf-name>unicast</saf-name>
                        <af-data>
                            <metri-styles>
                                <metric-style>
                                    <level>not-set</level>
                                </metric-style>
                            </metri-styles>
                        </af-data>
                    </af>
                </afs>
                <interfaces>
                    <interface>
                        <interface-name>Loopback0</interface-name>
                        <running></running>
                        <state>passive</state>
                        <interface-afs>
                            <interface-af>
                                <af-name>ipv4</af-name>
                            </interface-af>
                        </interface-afs>
                    </interface>
                    <interface>
                        <interface-name>Bundle-Ether88.88</interface-name>
                        <running></running>
                        <state>suppressed</state>
                        <circuit-type>level2</circuit-type>
                        <point-to-pont></point-to-pont>
                        <interface-afs>
                            <interface-af>
                                <af-name>ipv4</af-name>
                            </interface-af>
                        </interface-afs>
                    </interface>
                </interfaces>
            </instance>
        </instances>
    </isis>
```

And I want to filter the above XML file based on the below XML and get all child tags and values:

```xml
      <isis xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-clns-isis-cfg">
          <interfaces>
          </interfaces>
      </isis>
```

But let's say this filter is not static and it will change and I don't want to use any constant tag in the code. I want to be able to filter the main XML based on the second one without knowing the tags.

I have tried a couple of ways with lxml and built-in xml libraries.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add python code please-

Comment: I don't have any working python code. So, I am asking how to write the code. @LMC

Comment: SO is about answering concrete questions about existing code that's why I added my first comment. `How to write the code` is too broad.